# How to loop through all children in DB?

Tags: php, json, oracle, loops, pdo

Table in DB: (this are basically folders)

```
|groupId|  name   |parentId|
  1       system1     0
  2       subsystem1  1
  3       subsystem2  2
  4       subsubMisc  2
```

which should give

```
system1
  -subsystem1
    --subsystem2
    --subsubMisc
```

So far only the first children populate, subsystem1 isn't giving me children. I need this below with all children onward if they have any:

```
[
    {
        "name": "system1",
        "children": [
            {
                "name": "subsystem1",
                "children": [
                    {
                        "name": "subsystem2",
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "subsubMisc",
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

My code:

```
public function getTreeMenu()
{
    $result = false;
    $data = $this->repository->getRootParents(); // SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE parentId = 0 
    
    foreach ($data as $row) {
        $children = $this->repository->getFolderChildren($row['parentId']); // SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE pid = :parentId ORDER BY name
        if ($children !== false) {
            $result[] = array(
                'name' => $row['name'],
                'children' => $children,
            );
        } else {
            $result[] = array(
                'name' => $row['name'],
            );
        }
    }
    return $result;
}
```

This works only the first level. How do I loop sub-folders continuously for the given folders?

Comment: Is this a function? I see a `return $result;` but no function

Comment: Yes, it's a function inside a class.

Comment: Then show it as a function, complete function

Comment: A few example rows from the table would also assist in our understanding

Comment: Which db are you using? Because that makes quite a bit of difference. Some can compose this for you as part of the query rather than doing this in code after effectively downloading the entire table.

Comment: Traversing a data structure of arbitrary depth is more or less the defacto use case for a recursive function.

Comment: Oracle SQL is the database

Comment: If you will end up looping through everything in that table, I think you're better off just getting the lot in one query, and passing the array into a recursing function that loops your tree structure together.

Answer (score -1):

Oracle provides a very convenient [hierarchical query](https://www.dcodeman.com/docs/oracle-sql/8-hierarchical-query/) extension or you can use a SQL standard recursive query. You can get the entire hierarchy in a single query. ([see demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=f7a7c332850ce7d4be2a6e6fe9df1919))

```
select lpad ( ' ', 2*(level-1),'-') || name 
  from table_in_db 
 start with parent_id = 0 
 connect by parent_id = prior group_id ;
```

Note: The `lpad` function is not actually required. It provides the indention for each level and the dashes. Not exactly what you had but close. Your code should be able to construct the JSON.